# JIRA 7+ Edit Mail Handler

Tags: java, jira, jira-plugin

I am trying to build a JIRA 7 Plugin (a mail handler). In the official tutorial on how to build one, they build the class for the options dialogue like this:

```
public class EditDemoHandlerDetailsWebAction extends AbstractEditHandlerDetailsWebAction {...}
```

My problem is that in the meantime something seems to have changed. My IDE suggested either making this class abstract or implementing some more methods from the super-class (AbstractEditHandlerDetailsWebAction).

When I implement the missing classes I can't build my project anymore and get this error:

> name clash: setErrorMessages(java.util.Collection)
>   in
>   com.example.plugins.jira.demomailhandler.EditDemoHandlerDetailsWebAction
>   and setErrorMessages(java.util.Collection) in
>   webwork.action.ActionSupport have the same erasure, yet neither
>   overrides the other.

Does anyone have a clue what I am getting wrong and how to do this in 2017?

Thank you very much in advance!

**Edit #1**
Here some more info on the versions I use from my pom.xml:

```
<properties>
    <jira.version>7.2.2</jira.version>
    <amps.version>6.2.11</amps.version>
    <plugin.testrunner.version>1.2.3</plugin.testrunner.version>
    <atlassian.spring.scanner.version>1.2.13</atlassian.spring.scanner.version>
    <!-- This key is used to keep the consistency between the key in atlassian-plugin.xml and the key to generate bundle. -->
    <atlassian.plugin.key>${project.groupId}.${project.artifactId}</atlassian.plugin.key>
    <!-- TestKit version 6.x for JIRA 6.x -->
    <testkit.version>6.3.11</testkit.version>
</properties>
```

And the mail related dependencies:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.atlassian.jira</groupId>
        <artifactId>jira-mail-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>9.0.3</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.atlassian.mail</groupId>
        <artifactId>atlassian-mail</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.13</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
        <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.4</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/39753860/2220556 ?

Comment: Wow, thanks for the link this looks really helpful. I already found out to use jira-mail-plugin 9.0.3 with JIRA 7 and also managed to substitute User with ApplicationUser, but still can't get my handler to work. But I found some sources in the external libraries and hopefully will solve my issues with this. Will be posting my results as soon as I found out :-)

Answer (score 0):

It was enough to add these two methods:

```
@Override
public void addError(String s, String s1) {}

@Override
public void addErrorMessage(String s) {}
```

I didn't have to add the *setErrorMessages* method at all to get it working. My IDE (IntelliJ) is still whining and drawing a red line under the classname but everything seems to work for now.